# Check if any other select has same value set

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm currently working on some stuff that requires to check if any other selects has same values as the one im currently using.

When a user clicks on the 'Tilføj Periode' button, it should check if selects exists. If it does not exist then it can proceed calling the function. Also when pressing that button it sets 2 variables.

```
var period_interval     = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-interval option:selected').val();
var period_recurrence   = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-recurrence option:selected').val();
```

I'm using these to see if it exist

(Why is my page black? Browser addon - for my eyes)

[image]

So the issue here is that the 2 selects at the bottom (Add New Row) has 2 values set by a user. The user may NOT be able to create a new variation (row) if the interval and day/month/year etc. exists already.

So let's say id like to create a new one. See screenshot as example. I'd like a variation on every 5th day. When I click 'Tilføj periode' it should look through all rows and check for each select if the value from interval exists in that row and the day/month/year ALSO exists in same row. How would I do so?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
var period_interval     = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-interval option:selected').val();
var period_recurrence   = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-recurrence option:selected').val();
var bExists             = false;
if(jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option[value="'+period_recurrence+'"]:selected') && jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-interval option[value="'+period_interval+'"]:selected'))
{
    console.dir('exists');
}
else
{
    console.dir('noexist');
}
```

```
// Check if current variations are conflicting with the one we are trying to create
jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-interval option:selected').each(function() {
    if(period_interval == jQuery(this).val())
    {
        console.dir('interval exists');
        // It is conflicting - do not create
        bExists = true;
    }
    
    jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option:selected').each(function() {
        if(period_recurrence == jQuery(this).val())
        {
            console.dir('period exists');
            // It is conflicting - do not create
            bExists = true;
        }
    });
});
```

^ That one worked almost

Here's my whole code:

```
jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add').on('click', function()
{
    // Reset data
    var price               = 0;
    var period_interval     = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-interval option:selected').val();
    var period_recurrence   = jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-add-recurrence option:selected').val();
    var bExists             = false;
    if(jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option[value="'+period_recurrence+'"]:selected') && jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-interval option[value="'+period_interval+'"]:selected'))
    {
        console.dir('exists');
    }
    else
    {
        console.dir('noexist');
    }

    // // Check if current variations are conflicting with the one we are trying to create
    // jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-interval option:selected').each(function() {
    //  if(period_interval == jQuery(this).val())
    //  {
    //      console.dir('interval exists');
    //      // It is conflicting - do not create
    //      bExists = true;
    //  }
        
    // });
    
    // jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option:selected').each(function() {
    //  if(period_recurrence == jQuery(this).val())
    //  {
    //      console.dir('period exists');
    //      // It is conflicting - do not create
    //      bExists = true;
    //  }
    // });


    // jQuery('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option[value="'.period_interval.'"]:selected')


    return exists;
```

I think it should be quite simple, but I just can see the solution :/

## Edit - Forgot to add select html

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;"><?php echo '#'.$oID; ?></td>
    <td class="cell-price">
        <input type="number" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($oID)['_regular_price'][0]; ?>" class="input-small" placeholder="<?php _e('Amount', 'layback'); ?>">
    </td>
    <td class="cell-period">
        <div class="group">
            <select name="" id="" class="input-small vehicle--single-variations-interval">
                <option value="1" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every 2nd</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 3) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every 3rd</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 4) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every 4th</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 5) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every 5th</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period_interval'][0] == 6) echo 'selected'; ?>>Every 6th</option>
            </select>
            <select name="" id="" class="input-small vehicle--single-variations-recurrence">
                <option value="day" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period'][0] == 'day') echo 'selected'; ?>>Day</option>
                <option value="week" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period'][0] == 'week') echo 'selected'; ?>>Week</option>
                <option value="month" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period'][0] == 'month') echo 'selected'; ?>>Month</option>
                <option value="year" <?php if(get_post_meta($oID)['_subscription_period'][0] == 'year') echo 'selected'; ?>>Year</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cell-actions">
        <button attr-variationid="<?php echo $oID; ?>" class="btn small btn-danger vehicle--single-variations-remove"><?php _e('Delete', 'layback'); ?></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `^ That one worked almost` – hey, that is _almost_ a useful problem description :-) Please explain in what aspect it did _not_ work then.

Comment: You only have simple select fields that allow only one option to be chosen here, so this should not need to explicitly select `option:selected` in multiple places, `.val()` is enough to get you the value of the selected option already.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for a quick reply. I really did not dig too much into why it would work sometimes. But I've just wrote some code that works. I'll post it as a solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of. Thanks for fast responses.
Second of all.. I've found a solution.

I've decided to loop through each row. Setting a variable with each select and then comparing those variables according to the 'Add new' row selects.

```
jQuery('.vehicle-single-variation-tr').each(function() {

    var interval = jQuery(this).find('.vehicle--single-variations-interval option:selected').val();
    var recurrence = jQuery(this).find('.vehicle--single-variations-recurrence option:selected').val();

    if(period_interval == interval && period_recurrence == recurrence)
    {
        bExists = true;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below.

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];
var selectedValue=[];
var select="select_";
var counter=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#AddNew").on('click',function(){
       var dataSource=[];
       var option=''
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           var name=data[i].text;
           if($.inArray(name,selectedValue)==-1){
              dataSource.push(data[i]);
              option+='<option value="'+name+'">'+name+'</option>'
           }
       }
      var config={
        data: dataSource
      } 
      var id=select+counter;
      var selectcontrol=$("<select/>",{id:id});
      selectcontrol.html(option)
      selectcontrol.on('change',function(){
          var selvalue=$(this)[0].selectedOptions[0].label;
          if($.inArray(selvalue,selectedValue)==-1){
              selectedValue.push(selvalue);
           }
          $(this).attr("disabled",true)
      })
      $("#selectDiv").append(selectcontrol);
      
      counter++;
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' id='AddNew' value='Add New'/>
<div id='selectDiv'></div>
```

Comment: Hi!
Not really what I was looking for. They should still be able to use the selects even if the values exists. However, your code is quite cool. I do like the disable feature and it saying 'Duplicate'. Cool!